# PHP - Removing the effect of HTML tags in string - BUT displaying them as well?

Tags: php, html, replace, tags, strip

Consider `strip_tags()` .

```
strip_tags("<b>TEXT</b>");
```

Output:

> **TEXT**

But what if i want to nullify the effect of the tags but display them as well?

Output:

> <b>TEXT</b>

Would i have to use `preg_replace()` ? Or is there a more elegant solution available?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can HTML encode the string via [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

```
htmlspecialchars("<b>TEXT</b>");
```

Answer (score 6):

You can easily convert characters to their HTML entity using [htmlspecialchars](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or [htmlentities](http://uk.php.net/htmlentities). Make sure you check the PHP manual to determine what is most appropriate to your data, as both functions operate slightly differently.

You can then reverse the encoding with [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) and [html_entity_decode](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) - again, check which is most appropriate for your data.

Comment: htmlspecialchars is the only one usable function of these

Comment: What do you mean? They are all valid PHP functions, and each have their purpose. Perhaps the OP does only need `htmlspecialchars`, but that does not invalidate the usefulness of the other functions in similar situations.

Answer (score 2):

You could always just replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`, yeah?

Comment: will this also eliminate the need to use strip_slashes in the 1st place?

Comment: @wretrOvian strip_tags you mean? it is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use textarea tag as following:

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="20"><?php echo "<b>Text<b>"; ?></textarea>
```